# Sibling component is not getting updated parameter value from child component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have parent, child and sibling component. When we are changing parameter value in child component. sibling component method should trigger and updated value should get.

My problem is, i am able to trigger the method from parent component to sibling component but not getting updated value at trigger time. there is some delay.

There are two different approaches i am using for passing parameter and trigger method, that may be issue. Please help.

This method trigger from parent when zip code change from child component but not getting zip code value at sibling component at trigger time.

getSiblingSettingFn() {

}

Child Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
    @Output() childGInParameters = new EventEmitter<{ city: string, state: string, zip: string }>();

    city: any = "Palmdale";
    state: any = "CA";
    zip: any = "93551";

    setGeneralInfo() { // on change event
        this.childGInParameters.emit({ city: this.city, state: this.state, zip: this.zip });
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
import { SiblingComponent } from '../SiblingComponent';
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-cmp',
    template: '<child-cmp (childGInParameters)="getGeneralInfo($event)" > </child-cmp>
                <br/>
                <sib-cmp [zip]="zip" [state]="state" [city]="city" ></sib-cmp>'
})
class ParentCmp {
    @ViewChild('SiblingComponent') sibchild: SiblingComponent;

    getGeneralInfo(childGInParameters: any) {
        this.city = childGInParameters.city;
        this.state = childGInParameters.state;
        this.zip = childGInParameters.zip;

        this.sibchild.getSiblingSettingFn();
    }
}
```

Sibling Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sib-cmp'
})
class SiblingComponent {
    @Input() zip: any;
    @Input() state: any;
    @Input() city: any;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        const c: SimpleChange = changes.zip;
        this.zip = c.currentValue;
    }

    getSiblingSettingFn() {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: its not good practice to call method of other component from different component. You need to put one service to communicate between different component .

Answer (score 1):

Use Service to interact with different component other than parent-child direct relationship. So you may need Service that works in between Parent and Sibiling component level.

- Sharing Data from Parent to Child:  @Input
- Sharing Data from Child to Parent:  @ViewChild
- Sharing Data from Child to Parent:  @Output & EventEmitter
- Sharing Data Between Various Components:  Service

Refer component interaction - https://www.calibraint.com/blog/angular-components-interaction-methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
       if(changes.zip.previousValue){
          this.zip = changes.zip.currentValue;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have used same code but there is some gap getting zip code value. First method is calling then zip code value is getting. Both are not properly handle.